# How to neatly print new line in Groovy?

Tags: groovy

I was wondering if there is any neat way to write new line into the file from Groovy. I have the following script:

```
new File("out.txt").withWriter{ writer ->
    for(line in 0..100) {
            writer << "$line"
    }
}
```

I could use `writer << "$line\n"` or `writer.println("$line")`, but I was wondring if there is any way to use `<<` operator to append the new line for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use meta programming to create that functionality. An easy solution to change the behaviour of the << operator would be to use a custom category.

Example:

```
class LeftShiftNewlineCategory {
    static Writer leftShift(Writer self, Object value) {
        self.append value + "\n"
    } 
}
use(LeftShiftNewlineCategory) {
    new File('test.txt').withWriter { out ->
        out << "test"
        out << "test2"    
    }
}
```

More about categories here:
http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GROOVY/Groovy+Categories

Comment: This is nice stuff. I've just started with Groovy few days ago and wasn't aware of that feature. I must check it out! Thanks xlson.

Comment: You're welcome! :) There's many different ways to use meta-programming in Groovy to enhance existing APIs. The good thing with categories (imho) is that they are scoped so that you don't change behavior in all of your program. Check out this intro to Groovy meta-programming if you wanna learn more about it: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-pg06239.html

Answer (score 15):

It's a nice idea to ask the system for the correct line separator as these can change between operating systems.

```
writer << "Line 1" + System.getProperty("line.separator") + "Line 2"
```

Comment: Some systems require \n and others require \r\n. It's hard to tell, so let the system figure it out as per this example.

Answer (score 5):

Or you could just use three double-quotes

e.g.

```
def multilineString = """
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
consectetur adipiscing elit,
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
"""
println multilineString
```

Reference: http://grails.asia/groovy-multiline-string

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
writer << "$line" << "\n"
```

Which is shorthand for

```
writer << "$line"
writer << "\n"
```